# What is the meaning of the power notation in the access structure?

Tags: abe, access-control, monotone-access-structure

In the paper about ABE ([like this](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Ebwaters/publications/papers/cp-abe.pdf)), the access structure is defined as follow:

> Let ${P_1,P_2,...,P_n}$ be a set of parties. A collection $A⊆2^{\{P_1,P_2,...,P_n\}}$ is monotone if $∀B,C$: if $B∈A$ and $B⊆C$ then $C∈A$ ...

What is the meaning of this notation: $2^{\{P_1,P_2,...,P_n\}}$? Can you give some example while explaining?

Comment: you can accept the answer if it satisfactorily answered your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the powerset of all subsets of $\{P_1,\ldots,P_n\}$. Therefore

$$2^{\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}}=\{\{ \},\{P_1\},\{P_2\},\{P_3\},\{P_1,P_2\},\{P_1,P_3\},
\{P_2,P_3\},\{P_1,P_2,P_3\}\}
$$
for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the number 2 indicates certain restrictions about the elements in the subset. But it turns out to be a symbol.